# HTML5 date input accepts invalid dates?

Tags: google-chrome, date, datepicker, forms

Why can the HTML5 element `<input type="date">` let the user scroll through the dates to an invalid date such as `31 September 2014`?

*DEMO*: http://jsfiddle.net/oztjryx4/1/

Why does Chrome allow this to happen? How can I check if the date is invalid or does not exist?

Comment: Chrome won't yield a value for invalid dates. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/snnj94ke/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect such invalid dates with input.validity.badInput.
According to http://crbug.com/231811, the reason is simplicity.